# Rounding Numbers to Two Significant Figures

Tags: swift, rounding

I am sure this is an easy question to any of you are experienced in Swift, however, I just started learning how to program and have no idea where to start. What I am trying to do is a round a number to the nearest whole value, or to the third number. This is what I mean:

```
12.6 //Want rounded to 13
126 //Want rounded to 130
1264 //Want rounded to 1300
```

I know swift has a `.rounded()` function, and I have managed to use it to round the nearest 10th, 100th, etc., however, I cannot round the way I would like to. Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: Is that example what you want or what you're getting? Can you add the Swift code that shows what you tried?

Comment: That is an example of what I want, sorry, I'll edit the question.

Comment: What you want is rounding to two significant digits. If the result is supposed to be a string, then `NumberFormatter` can do that easily.

Comment: Yes, thank you, the word escaped my mind, I'll edit the title of the question. How can I round to two sig figs?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's one way to round any `Double` or `Int` (including negative numbers) to a given number of significant figures:

```
func round(_ num: Double, to places: Int) -> Double {
    let p = log10(abs(num))
    let f = pow(10, p.rounded() - Double(places) + 1)
    let rnum = (num / f).rounded() * f

    return rnum
}

func round(_ num: Int, to places: Int) -> Int {
    let p = log10(abs(Double(num)))
    let f = pow(10, p.rounded() - Double(places) + 1)
    let rnum = (Double(num) / f).rounded() * f

    return Int(rnum)
}

print(round(0.265, to: 2))
print(round(1.26, to: 2))
print(round(12.6, to: 2))
print(round(126, to: 2))
print(round(1264, to: 2))
```

Output:

> 0.27
>   1.3
>   13.0
>   130
>   1300

Comment: what do you as num approaches zero? there should be a check

Answer (score 3):

As stated by [Sulthan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/669586/sulthan) you can use [`NumberFormatter`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/numberformatter):

```
let formatter = NumberFormatter()

formatter.usesSignificantDigits = true
formatter.maximumSignificantDigits = 2
formatter.minimumSignificantDigits = 2

if let result = formatter.string(from: 12.6) {
    print(result)  // prints 13
}
```

Comment: Assuming you only want it as a string

Comment: @Kevin true, if you want `result` to be a numeric type you'll have to do `Int(result)`, `Double(result)`, etc. to convert it to the type you want

Answer (score 2):

One possibility to implement a rounding algorithm. I suppose you always want the result to be integer.

```
func round(_ number: Float, to digits: Int) -> Float {
    guard number >= 0 else {
        return -round(-number, to: digits)
    }

    let max = pow(10, Float(digits))

    var numZeros = 0
    var value = number

    while (value >= max) {
        value /= 10
        numZeros += 1
    }

    return round(value) * pow(10, Float(numZeros))
}

print(round(12.6, to: 2)) // 13
print(round(126, to: 2))  // 130
print(round(1264, to: 2)) // 1300
```